# can't give width and height in nav tag

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make navigation like this:
[image]

I started to this with `nav` tag but when I'm giving its width and height it looks like this:
[image]

```
#auzi{
  margin-left:55px;
  width:90px;
  height:35px;
  color:#246c41;
  background: url(https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-9/13646_802426683122032_8872692336592806117_n.jpg?oh=d9ebec474b44c2172aff91a26cbe8745&oe=5480A9F5&__gda__=1416669080_db2840f489895af5e3e8515bdc781921) no-repeat;
  text-align:center;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/1rgt9hor/)

Comment: By default, `a` is an inline element, so it can't get width and height. Try changing it to be an `inline-block`, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `<a>` is an inline element it don't accept any `height` or `width` just add the `display:block;` either `display: inline-block` to your `#auzi`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/1rgt9hor/1/)**

Comment: @AnupKhandelwal And more over i edited authors fiddle so he didn't style it till he wants his `<a>` to take width and height.

Comment: "Dont you see it take the width and height." What was that? I never said you dont need width and height. Your demo was not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
display:inline-block
```

to #auzi css.

Answer (score 0):

Make your outer div be display: table-cell, or give it a line-height of appropriate size.

```
#choose{
    width:675px;
    height:50px;
    display: table-cell;
    line-height: 85px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ndL7pvpm/)